# Silverlight RegisterScriptableObject scriptkey is always null

Tags: javascript, .net, silverlight

Had to post here this doesn't make any sense to me.

I am trying to call Silverlight functions from my javascript and the scriptkey I am using always comes up null.

I have this img in my markup that I want to initiate the Silverlight code.

```
<img alt="stop" src="stop.jpg" onclick="CallSilverlight();" />
```

Clicking that runs this JavaScript function.

```
function CallSilverlight() {
            var control = document.getElementById("silverlightControlHost");
            control.Content.Page.DoStuff();
        }
```

DoStuff() is a function in my silverlight object I am trying to register it as scriptable by using this code in my silverlight class.

```
public Main()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("Page", this);
}

[ScriptableMember]
public void DoStuff()
{
     MessageBox.Show("Hello from SL");
}
```

No idea what is wrong here, this is just like all the examples on the web but my Page in control.Content.Page.DoStuff(); throws this javascript error, am I missing something, this is driving me crazy.

Line: 67
Error: Unable to get value of the property 'Page': object is null or undefined

Comment: My bad, silverlightControlHost was my div id, I changed it to my silverlight objects id and everything is working now.  So much time lost on monumental stupidity.

Comment: Since there isn't really a useful answer to the question I suggest you simply delete this question.